# Cannot find the password of root in the fresh mysql install 5.7.20 on Redhat

Tags: mysql, linux

I see there are several similar questions asked already, but I am not able to find the answer.  So please help.

I installed mysql 5.7  on Redhat EL7.  I followed the instructions in the manual,

```
   sudo yum localinstall mysql57-community-release-el7-11.noarch.rpm

   sudo yum install mysql-community-server
```

All went fine, except that I can't find the temporary root password. I read that the temp password is in /var/log/mysqld.log, but the file is empty.

Any help?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try without any password. simply hit enter and further you can set password.

Answer (score 0):

I post this as an answer b/c i have less than 50 but have you tried "toor" it is often the default password of root. Also, in the official mysqld repository like the one on apt, you set the password during the setup... So, check these two solutions. If it is not that good luck to find your answer :)